# Segmentation fault using php dev server with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to set up a development environment for Laravel 4, but the php development server is quitting with a `Segmentation fault` error when I try to access index.php file in the the public folder of my laravel app.

I'm running OpenSUSE 12.3, and I installed php 5.4.20 through the `OpenSUSE BuildService - PHP` community repository. I installed laravel using `Composer version 565f86f30d9d9ef5ba6b9993e51a99affa98e14d 2013-10-15 00:53:02`. My project lives in a folder within my home folder.

If I navigate to `/path/to/laravel/project/public` in the terminal and run `php -S localhost:8000`, and then open `localhost:8000` in my browser (`Chromium 30.0.1553.0 (209444)`) and get a `No data received: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error. In the terminal I get the `Segmentation fault` error.

This is a default Lavarel 4 installation -- I have not changed any of the code included with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried just running the artisan command to start the php server process in Laravel?  Just go back up to your project root and type "php artisan serve" and then go to `http://localhost:8000`.  Maybe that will work.  Although if you are already running Linux maybe you can just set up an apache or nginx instance and run it that way?  I do the artisan serve method on my laptop for development.